# Java Issue with String: Trying to reverse the midpoint of String.. String out of Range exception

Tags: java, string, loops, indexoutofrangeexception, charat

I'm working on an assignment for one of my classes. I'm very new to java in general and for this problem I was asked to only use loops and the charAt(); command to reverse the midpoint of a string.  However, I came to an issue when I try to reverse the string after the midpoint.  It gave me an exception and I don't know how to make of it since it looks correct to me. Any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class PS4Reverse {

public static void main (String [] args) {

String x = "";

String t = "";

String full = "";

String rev = "";

String complete = "";

Scanner user = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter a string.");
x = user.nextLine();

int real = x.length();

int half = x.length();

half = half / 2;

int i = 0;


for (i = 0; i != half; i++)
{
    char n = x.charAt(i);
    full = full + n;

}


for (i = i; i != real; i++)
{
    char n = x.charAt(i);
    t = t + n;
}

int back = t.length();


System.out.println(back);
for (i = back; i != 0; i--)
{
    char n = t.charAt(i);
    rev = rev + n;
}


complete = full + rev;

System.out.println("Original String:\t\t" + x)
System.out.println("Reverse String:\t\t" + complete);


}
}
```

Thank all y'all very much in advance!

Comment: your last loop starts at the array's length, which is one past its last element.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, it helps if you're exact when telling us what exception is happening.  It is a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`, not a `String out of Range exception` or an `indexoutofrangeexception`.

Anyway, this is the issue:

```
int back = t.length();

for (i = back; i != 0; i--)
{
    char n = t.charAt(i);
```

The indexes are zero-baed, so if `t.length()` is 4, `t.charAt(4)` is going to be out of bounds.  You need to start at `t.length() - 1`.

Comment: You're also missing a semicolon after one of your `System.out.println()` statements, but I assume that's just a typo.

Answer (score 0):

You got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.StringIndexOutOfBoundsException: String index out of range: 5
    at java.lang.String.charAt(Unknown Source)
    at PS4Reverse.main(PS4Reverse.java:49)


int back = t.length(); // this code length of t string. But array indis is starting 0.
```

This means first item is 0 , last item must be back-1.

you use that;

```
for (i = back-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    char n = t.charAt(i);
    rev = rev + n;
}
```

Comment: This worked for me.. Thank you so much. I greatly appreciate it!

Comment: @GavinWebb [Here](http://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) is what to do when someone answers your question. To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark ✔ beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. There is no need to add a comment on your question or on an answer to say "Thank you".